# Why is bash expanding history/exclamation-mark when between single quotes

Tags: bash, quoting, history-expansion

I am creating a script to configure a server from scratch, part of this is postgres. One of the issues I'm having is if a random password has an exclamation it seems to be expanded by bash:

I want run the following postgres command:

```
alter user root with encrypted password 'D1£example!2eNZY6P$9examplePassword';
```

But from bash script using:

```
psql -c "command;"
```

Using:

```
runuser -l postgres -c "above cammand"
```

So I get this:

```
psqlcmd1="psql -c \"""alter user root with encrypted password 'D1£LF1A\!2eNZY6P$9examplePassword';""\""
runuser -l postgres -c "$psqlcmd1"
```

But bash expands the ! even though its between single quotes?

Also, I had tried the following [based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings) to escape the single quotes without luck :

```
runuser -l postgres -c "psql -c 'alter user root with encrypted password '"'"'D1£example!2eNZY6P$9examplePassword'"'"';'"
```

Comment: Let me parse that: `"psql -c \""` quote/unquote, then `"alter user root with encrypted password 'D1£LF1A\!2eNZY6P$9examplePassword';"` - another quote/unquote. So your `!` is actually in double quotes, not single.

Comment: So the effects of single quotes are negated when within double quotes?

Comment: Yes. Try `echo "'$SHELL'"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> psqlcmd1="psql -c \"""alter user root with encrypted password 'D1£LF1A\!2eNZY6P$9examplePassword';""\""
> ```

With history expansion turned off, the value of `psqlcmd1` is

```
psql -c "alter user root with encrypted password 'D1£LF1A\!2eNZY6PexamplePassword;"
```

Inside double quotes, the only characters that don't stand from themselves are `` \"$` ``, plus `!` if history expansion is enabled. Note in particular that `'` inside double quotes stands for itself: it doesn't start a string literal, the double quotes have already started one. Also note that since `$` starts a variable expansion, `$9` is expanded; its value is the 9th parameter to the current script of function, empty if there were fewer than 9 parameters.

Also note that `"foo""bar"` is the same thing as `"foobar"`: it's two string literals joined together, so it might as well be written as a single string literal.

Inside double quotes, you need to put a backslash before the characters `` \"$` `` if you want the resulting string to include that character. This doesn't work for `!`: `"!"` is the string `!` in a script, but invokes history expansion if that is enabled; `"\!"` is always the string `\!`. You need to use single quotes or no quotes around the `!`. Simplest would be to use a single-quoted literal: all characters inside single quotes stand for themselves, except for single quotes. To include a single quote in a single-quoted literal, end the literal, then use a backlash to quote a single quote, and start a single-quoted literal; or in other words, to include a single quote in a single-quoted literal, write `'\''`.

```
psqlcmd1='alter user root with encrypted password '\''D1£example!2eNZY6P$9examplePassword'\'';'
```